# UIImage and BLOB

Tags: ios, database, uiimage, blob, nsdata

I need to save an image in the database, that it is on a remote server. For that, i define a BLOB.

```
NSData *imagenData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagen.image);
```

My problem: when i receive the NSData from database and i parse to UIImage again, to show this image.

```
NSString imagenStr = [dict objectForKey:@"imagen"]; 
NSData imagenData = [imagenStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
self.imagen.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imagenData];
```

The image doesn't load at the use interface. Why? 
Sorry for my english, and thank you.

Comment: you should convert NSData to base64 or the like otherwise you may be losing data

Comment: You should show us how you're sending the object to the server, as well as how you're receiving it from the server. Manuel is right that if you're sending via mechanisms like JSON or XML, you should really use Base64 during the network operation.

Comment: Also, you might want to show us how you originally set `self.imagen.image` because you often want to go back to that original source, rather than using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` which can introduce some data loss. (If you're building it via `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, using that function is fine, but if you're reading it from a file, it's better to go back to that original file.)

Comment: I have a problems with that. Look at my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing an image as NSData, in order to present it on the UI it should be as simple as:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imagenData];
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, the syntax in your code is incorrect. It should be     NSString \*imagenStr = [dict etc...]. You are missing the astrick (\*). That can cause a bunch of other problems too...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i convert NSData to Base64.

```
NSData *imagenData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagen.image);
MetodosComunes *metodos = [[MetodosComunes alloc] init];
NSString *imagenStr = [metodos base64forData:imagenData];
```

The method base64forData:

```
-(NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Then, i need to show this saved image at the application, and i convert base64 to NSData:

```
- (NSData *)base64DataFromString: (NSString *)string
{
    unsigned long ixtext, lentext;
    unsigned char ch, inbuf[4], outbuf[3];
    short i, ixinbuf;
    Boolean flignore, flendtext = false;
    const unsigned char *tempcstring;
    NSMutableData *theData;

    if (string == nil)
    {
        return [NSData data];
    }

    ixtext = 0;

    tempcstring = (const unsigned char *)[string UTF8String];

    lentext = [string length];

    theData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: lentext];

    ixinbuf = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ixtext >= lentext)
        {
            break;
        }

        ch = tempcstring [ixtext++];

        flignore = false;

        if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            ch = ch - 'A';
        }
        else if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
        {
            ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
        }
        else if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
        {
            ch = ch - '0' + 52;
        }
        else if (ch == '+')
        {
            ch = 62;
        }
        else if (ch == '=')
        {
            flendtext = true;
        }
        else if (ch == '/')
        {
            ch = 63;
        }
        else
        {
            flignore = true;
        }

        if (!flignore)
        {
            short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
            Boolean flbreak = false;

            if (flendtext)
            {
                if (ixinbuf == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if ((ixinbuf == 1) || (ixinbuf == 2))
                {
                    ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                }

                ixinbuf = 3;

                flbreak = true;
            }

            inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

            if (ixinbuf == 4)
            {
                ixinbuf = 0;

                outbuf[0] = (inbuf[0] << 2) | ((inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
                outbuf[1] = ((inbuf[1] & 0x0F) << 4) | ((inbuf[2] & 0x3C) >> 2);
                outbuf[2] = ((inbuf[2] & 0x03) << 6) | (inbuf[3] & 0x3F);

                for (i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++)
                {
                    [theData appendBytes: &outbuf[i] length: 1];
                }
            }

            if (flbreak)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return theData;
}
```

When i show the image, the image is black. At the console appear this error:

May 16 17:04:13 MacBook-Pro-de-Alejandro.local pantallas[1608] : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
May 16 17:04:13 MacBook-Pro-de-Alejandro.local pantallas[1608] : ImageIO: PNG Extra compressed data